# Foursquare Specials API: How does foursquare retire specials?

Tags: api, foursquare

Does the "state" property change to "locked"? Are they removed altogether?

Basically, I store the ID of a special (along with some of the data) and want to test whether it still is a valid special or not at a later date. What's the best way to accomplish this?

I've been through the specials API countless times, and I can't find a property that simply describes whether or not the special is "active".

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a special can no longer be redeemed it's state will be set to "locked". See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/special for more details.

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't sure if that was just for specials that would be unlocked in the future or not.